# How to RenderPage when clicked on a link

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

So I have a `div`, in which I have an `a` element. I want the other `div` to Render another page (`RenderPage`) as soon as the `a` element in the other `div` is clicked.

```html
<div id="Left" style="width:29.49%; height:100%; border-style:solid; border-color:darkgray;">
    <h1 id="Pages"> Articles </h1><br />
    <a OnClick="LoadUE()">UE</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<a></a>
    <script>
        function LoadUnity() {

        }
        function LoadUE() {
            document.getElementById("Body").innerHTML = @{RenderPage("Bottom.cshtml")};
        }
    </script>
</div>
<div id="Body" style="width:69.49%; height:100%;">

</div>
```

Comment: `RenderPage` belongs to ASP.NET Web Pages, whereas you have tagged your question with "Razor Pages", which is very different. Can you clarify what type of application you have? How was it created?

Comment: @MikeBrind asp.net webforms

Comment: It's definitely NOT web forms. What tool did you use to create the site?

Comment: @MikeBrind A simple Razor3 Page in a ASP.NET Web Forms solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RenderPage` method only works on the server when the page is first executed. If you want to load partials in ASP.NET Web Pages (which is what you are using) from client script, you should remove the leading underscore from the file name and then create an AJAX request to load it. Here's an example that uses [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function loadUE() {
            fetch('/bottom')
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = result;
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

As a side note, the ASP.NET Web Pages framework is pretty much dead. If you are just learning and have a choice, you should use Razor Pages instead: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/